# Hill function (equation) vs a gene

Tags: equation-solving, code-review

So im trying to make one equation equal another to solve for all physically realistic values of $X$. Hill function is:

$$
F(X)=\frac{1}{1+(\frac{X}{K})^n} 
$$

and Gene Z equation is:

$$
Z(X) = -\frac{1}{4} X + 0.8
$$

for $X = 0$ to $4$, $n = 6$, $K = 1$...(I assume "physically realistic values" means real values). I am actually unsure of how to put a limit restriction on the $X$ values so that would be a great help, otherwise I feel like this is relatively simple, just need some guidance on whether or not I've done this correctly :).. Here's some code.

```
clear [n];
n = 6;
k = 1;
Z[x_] := -x/4 + 0.8
z = Z[x];
F[k_, n_, x_] := 1/(1 + (x/k)^n)
hillf = F[1, n, x];
Reduce[hillf == z, x, Reals]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The `Clear` function starts with an uppercase C; in general all built-in functions in *Mathematica* start with an uppercase letter.

2) Generally speaking it's good practice not to start your own variable names with uppercase letters to avoid confusion. In particular, it's a good idea never to have single-letter uppercase symbols. These can generate sneaky conflicts with built-in ones (`N`, `D`, `K`, `C`, `E`, `I`, and I'm sure many more that I can't recall off the top of my head).

3) You also had an unnecessary definition of the function `Z` which was then assigned to the symbol `z`. I am not sure what you were trying to accomplish there.

4) Domain restrictions can be expressed as inequalities and added to the set of equations for `Solve` or `Reduce`.

Having said that, you can use the following:

```
Clear[n, k, x, z, f];
z[x_] := -x/4 + 0.8
f[k_, n_, x_] := 1/(1 + (x/k)^n)

Reduce[{f[1, 6, x] == z[x], 0 <= x <= 4}, x, Reals]

(* Out: x == 0.96072 || x == 3.19625 *)
```

Sometimes it may also be useful to get a feeling for the functions you are dealing with by plotting them over the region of interest:

```
Plot[{z[x], f[1, 6, x]}, {x, 0, 4}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: @Steve glad it helped

Comment: Actually, you only missed one from your list of reserved capital letters: `O[]`. ;)